# How Do I Disable Google Maps?

Tags: firefox

Can anyone tell me how to disable Google Maps or stop it from loading? I use Windows 7 with Firefox. Every time I log on I get an additional tab with Google maps. Every time I refresh the page, click the Home icon, or open any site, I get another Google Map tab.

It's driving me crazy to get 12+ tabs all opened to Google and it slows the web down terribly. I suspect it's constantly running in the background. I hate it and will reformat if I have to to get rid of it.

PS Internet Explorer works fine, no problems there, but I prefer Firefox.

Comment: What URL opens?

Comment: Need more info. When you say "Every time I log on" - do you mean log on to the computer or start up FireFox? Do you get the extra Google Maps window every time you open a new FF window? New FF Tab? What is your Home page set to? From the little bit of info you supplied, it sounds like your home page may be set to a value that directly or indirectly requests Google Maps - try changing your Home page to anything else (even blank).

Answer (score 1):

Try fiddling with setting in Firefox. The setting in Tools-->Options-->General-->When firefox starts(drop down). Select some other options and see if it solves the problem.